# Silverlight: Binding being called multiple times

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a XAML element that binds to a property of the `DataContext`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="SectionViewModels" />
```

This binds to a property:

```
    public IList<SectionViewModel> SectionViewModels
    {
        get
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

When the page is loaded, this property is called multiple times, even though I haven't fired any `PropertyChanged` events. Is this to be expected, or does it mean I have a bug?

(I'm building a Silverlight app on Windows Phone 7.)

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the specifics of your issue, you should use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for this sort of thing - if you're binding directly to a collection in Silverlight or WP7, an ObservableCollection will eliminate 99.9% of garbage you will deal with trying to create a cross-thread binding yourself.

Comment: The reason I'm not using an `ObservableCollection` is because the `Section` objects are in one, and the `SectionViewModels` are a query on that collection. By using an enumerable instead of a collection, I don't have to worry about the two staying in sync.